# Launching file from Ruby on Mac OS (as if it was double-clicked in Finder)

Tags: ruby, macos

I want to 'launch' file from Ruby on Mac OS. I.e., I want to write something like:

```
launch 'my.pdf'
```

...and have Preview (default program associated with PDF files) showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
exec 'open my.pdf'
```

to execute the osx shell command 'open' which will launch the associated application

Comment: Good enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `exec` replaces the current process (i.e. the ruby script). You might want to use [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system) instead.